# Can I use web3.shh with Parity client?

Tags: web3js, parity, whisper, shh

I'm trying to whisper a message using `web3.shh` following the example here: https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Whisper-Overview

```
web3.shh.post({ "topic": 't', "payload": 'p'});
```

And it throws an error:

```
Error: Method not found
      at Object.InvalidResponse (/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:35:16)
      at RequestManager.send (/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:61:22)
      at Shh.send [as post] (/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:145:58)
      at Context.done (test/index.js:33:23)
```

My Parity client is running with the following arguments:

```
parity -l all \
       --mode "active" \
       --unlock $ALICE,$BOB \
       --password $CONFIG_DIR/password \
       --chain $CHAINS_DIR/$CHAIN \
       --db-path $DB_PATH \
       --keys-path $DB_PATH/keys \
       --identity $IDENTITY \
       --no-discovery \
       --reserved-peers $CONFIG_DIR/peers.enodes \
       --jsonrpc-port "8545" \
       --jsonrpc-interface "0.0.0.0" \
       --jsonrpc-apis "web3,eth,net,parity,parity_accounts,parity_set,traces,rpc,personal,signer" \
       --jsonrpc-hosts "all" \
       --author $COINBASE \
       --reseal-min-period "10" \
       --ui-interface "0.0.0.0" \
       --ui-port "8180" \
       --ui-no-validation \
       $*
```

Comment: That's scheduled for the 1.8 release. The documentation is a bit fast with this one.

Comment: yes, as Rando said, you should switch to the latest version and also try to use web3@1.0.0-beta30 or whatever version is the latest...